# How to make a call from manager api methog originate

Tags: agi

I am trying to make a call to a PSTN number using dahdi, but I am unable to originate it through originate command please tell me how to use this method in asterisk-java.

Answer (score 0):

```
AMI Example

Action: Originate
Channel: DAHDI/1/123456789 ;PSTN Channel
Context: default
Exten: 101
Priority: 1
Callerid: Asterisk Automatic Wardial


extensions.conf

[default]
exten => 101,1,Dial(SIP/101,45)
exten => 101,n,Hangup()

this context make a bridge between SIP/101 and DAHDI/1/123456789
```